# Unable to retrieve input value using dom

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var a=document.getElementById("one").value;
      console.log(a);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="one" name="acc" value="iss">
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code snippets I am trying to print the value associated with input which has id ="one".

But I am getting error as

> cannot read property 'value' of null.

Comment: You need to place the script part at the end of the body or use window.onload

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your JavaScript at the end of the body. Placing it in head, means, it will execute even before the DOM elements are ready. Placing it at the end of body, means, JS will execute after the body elements are loaded:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="one" name="acc" value="iss" />
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var a = document.getElementById('one').value;
    console.log(a);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you use JQuery, then your code should be in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the `<script>...</script>` part at the end of your document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="one" name="acc" value="iss">
        <script>
          var a=document.getElementById("one").value;
          console.log(a);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you use `document.onready` event:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          document.addEventListener("load", function() {
              var a=document.getElementById("one").value;
              console.log(a);
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="one" name="acc" value="iss">
    </body>
</html>
```